# Strange SQL issue with Intersection operator

Tags: sql, sqlite

What I was trying to do is:

I have 2 tables first and second. I want to group records in table first by t2_ids and t3_ids columns. Afterwards filter all the records from table first with the selection of records from the table second where second.t2_ids contains first.t2_ids AND second.t3_ids contains first.t3_ids.

But somehow I get an error `Query Error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: v.t2_ids`. Could you please help me to fix the error? I'm not a PRO in SQL so I might miss something. Thanks a lot!

Sample DB tables creation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `first` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  t2_ids TEXT NOT NULL,
  t3_ids TEXT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `first` (`id`, `t2_ids`, `t3_ids`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2'),
  ('2', '1', '3'),
  ('3', '1', '2'),
  ('4', '4', '2');
  
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `second` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  t2_ids TEXT NOT NULL,
  t3_ids TEXT NOT NULL
);
 INSERT INTO `second` (`id`, `t2_ids`, `t3_ids`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2'),
  ('2', '1', '3'),
  ('3', '1', '2'),
  ('4', '4', '2');
```

QUERY

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM first AS v 
GROUP BY v.t2_ids, v.t3_ids 
INTERSECT 
SELECT a.* 
FROM second AS a 
WHERE 
(v.t2_ids = (a.t2_ids LIKE "%v.t2_ids%") 
AND 
v.t3_ids = (a.t3_ids LIKE "%v.t3_ids%"))
```

Comment: `SELECT *` with GROUP BY does not make sense. Also `a.t2_ids LIKE "%v.t2_ids%"` does not make sense. Although the error you get is obvious, what you want to do is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example query it is really hard to get what you needs are.
As far as I can guess you're trying to join tables using LIKE conditions. Here is how I'd do that

```
SELECT v.* 
  FROM fst a 
  join sec v
    on a.t2_ids LIKE '%'||v.t2_ids||'%' 
   AND a.t3_ids LIKE '%'||v.t3_ids||'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The set-operators (`UNION`/`INTERSECT'/ and so on) operate on the results of queries.  Each of the subqueries used needs to stand on its own.

The problem is this subquery:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM second AS a 
WHERE v.t2_ids = (a.t2_ids LIKE '%v.t2_ids%')  AND 
      v.t3_ids = (a.t3_ids LIKE '%v.t3_ids%')
```

First, I really have no idea why you are using `=` on the result of a `LIKE` expression.  But the first error is that `v` is not defined.  I'm looking at the `FROM` clause.  And it is not defined, so that is quite clear.

Comment: But I set it as `FROM first AS v`. So it should recognize it, no? So should I replace `v.t2_ids = (a.t2_ids LIKE '%v.t2_ids%')` with simple `a.t2_ids LIKE '%v.t2_ids%'`?

Comment: @JohnDoe . . . No.  That is what this answer is trying to explain.